# Submit data AJAX with jQuery confirmation dialog and clear form value

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, cakephp

I have a form where users can send gifts to each other for some amount, and I want them to be informed that gift is cost such amount when sending it. I have manage to open a dialog box but can't process ajax submission when user click on "Yes". It's not passing to server. However when I submitting without dialog box, it's working fine. Please help. Thanks in advance! here is the script:

```
<div id="gift_sent" style="float: left; width: 370px; margin: 5px 0 5px 0; display: none;"><?php echo ucfirst(__('Gift Sent', true)) ?></div>

<div style="float: left; width: 370px; margin: 50px 0 10px 0;">

<?php // echo $this->Form->create('Gift', array('action' => 'sent/' . $user_obj['User']['id'] . '/' . $gift['GiftPhoto']['id'], 'div' => false, 'id' => "submit_".$gift['GiftPhoto']['id'])); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Gift', array('div' => false, 'id' => "submit_".$gift['GiftPhoto']['id'])); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $user_obj['User']['id'])); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('sender_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $user_object['id'])); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('gift_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $gift['GiftPhoto']['id'])); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label' => 'Greetings, 240 characters max', 'rows' => '5', 'style' => 'width: 350px;', 'div' => false )); ?>

<div class="clr"></div>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Send'); ?>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var link = "<?php echo $html->url("/gifts/sent/" . $user_obj['User']['id'] . '/' . $gift['GiftPhoto']['id']) ?>";

$( "#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>" ).submit(function( event ) {

event.preventDefault();

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
return false;
});

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:190,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 330,
  modal: true,
    buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: "POST",
data: $(this).serialize(),
url: link,
// url: "<?php echo $html->url("/gifts/sent/" . $user_obj['User']['id'] . '/' . $gift['GiftPhoto']['id']) ?>",
success: function() {
    $('#gift_sent').show();
    $(':input', '#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('');
    }
        });
            $(this).dialog("close");
            },

            "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }
    }
});

});
</script>



<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Send a Gift">
<p>This Gift Cost <?php echo ($gift_cost); ?> Points to send. You sure you want to continue?</p>
</div>
```

This is a working copy without dialog box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>').bind('submit', function(event) {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $html->url("/gifts/sent/" . $user_obj['User']['id'] . '/' . $gift['GiftPhoto']['id']) ?>",
    data: $(this).serialize(),

    success: function() {
    $('#gift_sent').show();
    $(':input', '#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('');
    }
});
return false; 
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is your "Yes" quoted and your "No" unquoted? And check your error log - does the JS engine throw you any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes or No is the dialog box buttons. I don't see any errors in logs.

Answer (score 0):

HI you've got some errors in your code:

1. button Yes is quoted and No isnt
2. You've got two binding on the created form on submit watch:

   ```
   //every form in your code
   $('form').submit(function () {
       if (!submit) {
           $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
           return false;
       }
   });

   //concrete one
   $('#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto ']['id ']); ?>').bind('submit',...);`
   ```

Fix this and run console in your browser and watch if is there a problem.
And its not recommend to mix PHP and JS I looks really bad, try use data-xxx attribute on your html elements and get there by jQuery $().attr.

Comment: Hi petkopalko,... I modified a script a bit, but still can't pass submission to server. I don't see any errors in console. However when I go direct without dialog box it's working fine. But I need to show confirmation dialog for user to see amount he's getting charged and confirm that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've got problem with quotes:
`'#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>'` has to be
`"#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>"`
also here: `url: "<?php echo $html->url("/gifts/sent/" . $user_obj['User']['id'] . '/' . $gift['GiftPhoto']['id']) ?>"`
and here: `$(':input', '#submit_<?php echo ($gift['GiftPhoto']['id']); ?>')`